# How to expand multiple macros in Elixir?

Tags: macros, elixir

I'm starting my adventure with Elixir and I need a little bit o help.

I'm trying to simplify my structs definition and validation by using macros. The goal is to automatically inject `defstruct` and Vex library validators based on provided options in modules using it.

I've come up with the code as follows:

```
defmodule PdfGenerator.BibTypes.TypeDefinition do
  @callback valid?(%{}) :: boolean

  defmacro __using__(mod: mod, style: style, required: required, optional: optional) do
    required_props = required |> Enum.map(&{:"#{&1}", nil})
    optional_props = optional |> Enum.map(&{:"#{&1}", nil})

    quote location: :keep do
      defstruct unquote([{:style, style}] ++ required_props ++ optional_props)
      @behaviour PdfGenerator.BibTypes.TypeDefinition
      use Vex.Struct

      def cast(%{} = map) do
        styled_map = Map.put(map, :style, unquote(style))
        struct_from_map(styled_map, as: %unquote(mod){})
      end

      defp struct_from_map(a_map, as: a_struct) do
        keys =
          Map.keys(a_struct)
          |> Enum.filter(fn x -> x != :__struct__ end)

        processed_map =
          for key <- keys, into: %{} do
            value = Map.get(a_map, key) || Map.get(a_map, to_string(key))
            {key, value}
          end

        a_struct = Map.merge(a_struct, processed_map)
        a_struct
      end

      validates(
        :style,
        presence: true,
        inclusion: [unquote(style)]
      )
    end

    Enum.each(required, fn prop ->
      quote location: :keep do
        validates(
          unquote(prop),
          presence: true
        )
      end
    end)
  end
end
```

And I'm using this macro in another module:

```
defmodule PdfGenerator.BibTypes.Booklet do
  use PdfGenerator.BibTypes.TypeDefinition,
    mod: __MODULE__,
    style: "booklet",
    required: [:title],
    optional: [:author, :howpublished, :address, :month, :year, :note]
end
```

I want `PdfGenerator.BibTypes.Booklet` module, after macro expansion, to look as follows:

```
defmodule PdfGenerator.BibTypes.Booklet do
  defstruct style: "booklet",
            title: nil,
            author: nil,
            howpublished: nil,
            address: nil,
            month: nil,
            year: nil,
            note: nil

  @behaviour PdfGenerator.BibTypes.TypeDefinition
  use Vex.Struct

  def cast(%{} = map) do
    styled_map = Map.put(map, :style, "booklet")
    struct_from_map(styled_map, as: %PdfGenerator.BibTypes.Booklet{})
  end

  defp struct_from_map(a_map, as: a_struct) do
    keys =
      Map.keys(a_struct)
      |> Enum.filter(fn x -> x != :__struct__ end)

    processed_map =
      for key <- keys, into: %{} do
        value = Map.get(a_map, key) || Map.get(a_map, to_string(key))
        {key, value}
      end

    a_struct = Map.merge(a_struct, processed_map)
    a_struct
  end

  validates(
    :style,
    presence: true,
    inclusion: ["booklet"]
  )

  validates(
    :title,
    presence: true
  )
end
```

As you can see, based on `required` option, I'm trying to expand to `Vex`-specific macro (which in turn should be expanded further on in `Vex.Struct` macro definition) `validates(:<PROP_NAME>, presence: true)` for every value in `required` list. 
This macro code works (but without these validators for required values) when I remove last block from `__using__` macro:

```
Enum.each(required, fn prop ->
  quote location: :keep do
    validates(
      unquote(prop),
      presence: true
    )
  end
end)
```

But with it, when I'm trying to issue following command in the `iex` console: `%PdfGenerator.BibTypes.Booklet{}`

I get:

```
** (CompileError) iex:1: PdfGenerator.BibTypes.Booklet.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct PdfGenerator.BibTypes.Booklet
```

Any idea, what am I doing wrong? Any hint would be greatly appreciated as I'm pretty new to the whole Elixir and macros world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not provide the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it’s extremely hard to test the solution, but at the first glance the issue is you expect some magic from [`Kernel.SpecialForms.quote/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#quote/2), while it does not *implicitly inject anything anywhere*, it just *produces an AST*.

When you call

```rb
Enum.each(...)
```

as the last line of `quote do` block, the result of this call *is returned as AST* from `quote do`. That said, the current `__using__` implementation injects the result of the call to `quote do: :ok`, which is apparently `:ok`. What you need, is to build the list of clauses to be injected:

```rb
defmacro __using__(mod: mod, ...) do
  # preparation
  ast_defstruct =
    quote location: :keep do
      # whole stuff for defstruct
    end

  # NB! last term will be returned from `__using__`!
  [
    ast_defstruct |
    Enum.map(required, fn prop ->
      quote location: :keep,
        do: validates(unquote(prop), presence: true)
    end)
  ]
```

By using [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) we *collect* quoted ASTs for each element, and *append them* to already built AST for `defstruct` creation. We return a list (which is a proper AST,) containing many clauses.

Still, I am unsure if this is the only glitch due to lack of MCVE, but this is definitely the proper fix to start with.

Comment: Yes, that was it. And I forgot the very simple fact: every function in Elixir returns something. Thank you very much for your help and time put in :)